# Como fazer para imprimir acentuação em um projeto Console Application .NET Core

Tags: c#, acentuação, .net-core

```
using System;

namespace MediaDoisNumeros
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Int16 numero1, numero2;
            Double media;

            Console.Write("Digite o numero 1 : ");
            numero1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Digite o numero 2 : ");
            numero2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            media = (numero1 + numero2) / 2;

            Console.WriteLine("A média dos dois numeros é {0}", media);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

**Saída impressa no console :**

*A m├®dia dos dois numeros ├® 5*

**Como fazer para que seja impressa corretamente :**

*A média dos dois numeros é 5*

Comment: Bem vindo, dê um [tour] no site e veja [ask].

Comment: Fora este código ter uns problemas de estilo e robustez, qual o problema? O `média` no texto está dando problema? Qual o erro apontado? Onde está compilando? O arquivo `.cs` está gravado em UTF-8 pelo editor?

Comment: A robustez do código não causa preocupação.
O problema é que o texto acentuado não é exibido corretamente.
Sim O média não e exibido corretamente.
O erro apontado é como utilizar acentuação em um projeto Console Application .NET Core.
Sim o arquivo .cs está gravado em unicode ( UTF-8 com assinatura ) - página de código 65001 pelo editor.

Comment: `O erro apontado é como utilizar acentuação em um projeto Console Application .NET Core` isso não é um erro que o compilador aponte. Só aparece errado? aí o problema deve ser onde está sendo mostrado, como eu não sei onde está compilando, rodando, não tenho como ajudar.

Comment: agradeço pelo esforço em tentar compreender o problema, mas me parece que não está preocupado em ajudar, e sim em que eu formule a pergunta de acordo com seus preceitos. Sinto muito não ter o seu nível de conhecimento para formular a pergunta de forma que lhe agrade.

Comment: @EricCastro se eu entendi direito, tente fazer o seguinte: Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

Comment: @miltoncamara muito obrigado cara acabei de achar esta solução no stackOverFlow em ingles acabei de testar funcionou mesmo, e vi sua resposta. Valeu!
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750203/how-to-write-unicode-characters-to-the-console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Para poder imprimir as acentuações é necessário definir o encoding do output do console, para isso adicione `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` no início do seu código.

Ficando assim:

```
using System;

namespace MediaDoisNumeros
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

            Int16 numero1, numero2;
            Double media;

            Console.Write("Digite o numero 1 : ");
            numero1 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.Write("Digite o numero 2 : ");
            numero2 = Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine());

            media = (numero1 + numero2) / 2;

            Console.WriteLine("A média dos dois numeros é {0}", media);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```